# Integration of react native with android auto

Tags: react-native, android-auto

How can I integrate React native app with Android Auto?

In AndroidManifest.xml I added these lines

`<meta-data     android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"     android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />`

`<service android:name="com.shopify.rnandroidauto.CarService" android:exported="true">`
`<intent-filter>`
`<action android:name="com.google.android.car.action.CAR_APP" />`
`</intent-filter>`
`</service>`

Is there any package need to install for integrating React native apps with android auto?